# how to remove duplicate element from two array

Tags: php

This is my array

```
(
    "userServiceIds": "1,2,3",
    "enggServiceIds": "4,5,6,2,1"
)
```

as `"userServiceIds"` has to cross check with `"enggServiceIds"` and  `"enggServiceIds"` has to cross check with `"userServiceIds"`

as OUTPUT need only

```
"userServiceIds": "1,2,3"
"enggServiceIds": "4,5,6"
```

Comment: what is unique duplicate on earth  ?

Comment: sorry i change with it

Comment: please show us your code so far?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for `array_diff`.

```
$data = [
    'userServiceIds' => [1,2,3],
    'enggServiceIds' => [4,5,6,2,1]
];

$data['enggServiceIds'] = array_diff($data['enggServiceIds'], $data['userServiceIds']);
```